# Drupal 6 listing taxonomy terms in views

Tags: drupal-6, view, taxonomy

I have a vocabulary call jobs, I have multiple terms 'Doctor', 'Teacher', 'Bus Driver'

Is there no way yo output this list using views? I have tried terms and all terms. I just get a blank output:

```
All terms:
All terms:
All terms:
All terms:
```

All terms:

I could write a module to do this but want a quick way to list them. Am I missing something? I am not as experienced with D6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are first creating a View, you get to pick the type of view. Most often you'll pick Node, but in your case you should pick Term. That way you'll be creating a list of Terms.

Comment: That worked first time! As I said think D7 has done away with this now. You saved me a fair chunk of time. Thanks.